# Is it correct to refuse entry to masjid for no mask or vaccine

Tags: masjid

Is it correct to refuse entry to masjid for not wearing a mask? Is it correct to kick someone out of a masjid, such as during Friday khutbah, for not wearing a mask? Is it correct to deny entry for not having vaccine?

Comment: This looks like a fatwa request and we are not a fatwa site.

Comment: This is a question because this is happening right now and we need to know whether it is correct.

Comment: Then you should ask a scholar as stated this is not a fatwa site. We cannot give a fatwa because we simply have not the required knowledge.

Comment: I understand this is a new topic. I thought I could get answer with sources that attempts to give some guidance, not a fatwa to base decisions on.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Dr. Abdullah bin Hamid Ali](https://lamppostedu.org/vaccine-passes), Associate Professor of Islamic law and Prophetic Tradition at Zaytuna College in Berkeley, California, it is not permissible to deny unvaccinated entry to a masjid:

> The truth is that the masjid belongs to Allah. “And the mosques belong
> to God. So, do not call on anyone along with God” (Q 58:18). This
> means no one person nor group has the authority to determine who can
> and cannot enter it, besides those who Allah has already barred from
> it (drunkards, menstruating women, men in major ritual impurity,
> etc.). Denying someone entry to the masjid without a valid excuse is
> unlawful, sinful, and unethical.

This also means denying entry to unmasked is also not allowed.

It is [not permissible](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/45651/the-ruling-on-being-silent-and-speaking-during-the-khutbah-sermon-on-friday) to talk during khutbah or to tell someone to not talk. Therefore, you can't ask someone to leave the masjid during a khutbah.

Comment: The imam can talk during the khotbah to a specific person in the audience the prophet even paused the khutbah to speak with somebody!